# Machine learning - Calculating the importance of a "value" in a variable

Tags: r, variables, machine-learning, neural-network, random-forest

I’m analyzing a medical dataset containing 15 variables and 1.5 million data points. **I would like to predict hospitalization and more importantly which type of medication may be responsible.** The medicine-variable have around 700 types of drugs. *Does anyone know how to calculate the importance of a "value" (type of drug in this case) in a variable for boosting?* ***I need to know if ‘drug A’ is better for prediction than ‘drug B’ both in a  variable called ‘medicine’.***
The logistic regression model is able to give such information in terms of p-values for each drug, but I would like to use a more complex method. Of cause you can create a binary variable of each type of drug, but this gives 700 extra variables and does not seems to work very well. I’m currently using r. I really hope you can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance! Kind regards Peter

Comment: I have tried to narrow it by an example and boosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see `varImp()` in library `caret`, which supports all the ML algorithms you referenced.

Comment: Did the job, Thanks!!